# How to handle msToBlob producing security error on IE?

Tags: javascript, image, svg, canvas, blob

So my problem is I can't export png file from a canvas. I have used [canvas-toBlob](https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js) to polyfill toBlob method. But I face security issue error on callback msToBlob().
[Line of respected error on IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJO3X.png)

Here are my specific codes:

```
    const img = new Image();
    const svg = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
    const url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

    img.onload = () => {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.scale(2, 2);
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      ctx.restore();
      DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

      canvasRef.current.toBlob((imageBlob) => {
        triggerDownload(imageBlob, 'avatar.png');
      }, 'image/png');
    };

    img.src = url;
```

I've tried image cross origin and it doesnt work. Any other solution?

Comment: Why did you tag your question with svg? Do you draw an svg image on that canvas? Can you post a [mcve] of what you have?

Comment: yes, I already update the code. @Kaiido